# How to request mic and camera chrome permissions in one popup like Appear.in does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Appear.in has it so they request both mic and camera access in the same popup. I can't find any answers on how to do this, does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) from **Mozilla Web API**, it prompts the user for the permission and produces a MediaStream. Mozilla provides a good example for that:

```
// Prefer camera resolution nearest to 1280x720.
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.
```

It's easy to handle the stream that we get as it comes even with event handlers.